# Find SSRS subscriptions that never ran successful in the past 30 days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to write a SQL select statement to find the SSRS subscriptions that never successfully ran in the past 30 days so I can disable those subscriptions.

Anyone got an idea how to do that? Since execution logs create unique records every time when a job runs I was trying to group them by the report path but got stuck there. Can someone help me?

My thoughts was like:

```
SELECT ItemPath
FROM [ReportServer].dbo.ExecutionLog3 EX
GROUP BY ItemPath, Status, TimeEnd
HAVING Ex.TimeEnd >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
   AND Status != 'rsSuccess'
```

Comment: Why are your clauses in the `HAVING` and not the `WHERE`?

Comment: Because I'm looking for a report that has never ran successfully in the past 30 days. If I don't group them how can I find out if they kept failing over time in the past 30 days and they never ran successfully. If it ran successful even for once in the past 30 days, I don't want to see those ItemPath s in the result.
Here's a updated thought:
SELECT 
 P.ItemPath, COUNT(*)
 FROM 
  ( SELECT * FROM [ReportServer].dbo.ExecutionLog3 EX WHERE Ex.TimeEnd >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())) P
GROUP BY P.ItemPath,P.Status
HAVING Status != 'rsSuccess'

Comment: But neither of the clauses in the `HAVING` use aggregation, so why are they there and not in the `WHERE`? The `HAVING` clause is used when you want to compare to an aggregated value. Like `HAVING SUM(Price) > 1000`.

Comment: What happens if the subscription never ran at all in the last 30 days?

Comment: Execution log only shows the subscriptions that ran, and I'll eventually write a stored procedure to disable those subscriptions which always failed in the past 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm to help you:

```
With
Subscriptions As
(
    Select SubscriptionId, SubscriptionName
    From dbo.TableOfSubscriptions
)
, Executions As
(
    Select SubscriptionId, ExecutionStatus, Count (*) NumExecutions
    From dbo.TableOfExecutions
    Group By SubscriptionId, ExecutionStatus
)
, SubscriptionsExecutions As
(
    Select 
        SubscriptionId, SubscriptionName
        , IsNull((Select Sum (NumExecutions) From Executions Where ExeuctionStatus = 'Failed'), 0) ExecutionFailed
        , IsNull((Select Sum (NumExecutions) From Executions Where ExeuctionStatus = 'Success'), 0) ExecutionSuccessful
    From Subscriptions
)
Select *
From SubscriptionsExecutions
Where ExecutionSuccessful = 0
and ExecutionFailed <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can't get the result I want.

Comment: What issue are you running into?